# Find the equivalent capacitance

Tags: capacitance

[image: img]

I've only started to study series and parallel combinations of capacitors. This is a question from my notebook, you have to find the equivalent capacitance. I can't figure out if the capacitors are in parallel or series. In a simple circuit I can do it, but **how can I figure out what type of connection it is** in complex cases like this. Is there a certain way of approaching? I've tried solving but in vain.

Comment: Start by labelling potential of different points in the given circuit diagram. This will lead you to the answer.

Comment: @Mitchell http://imgur.com/CkGIAoa Is this what you mean? **What can I conclude from it? **

Comment: Yup, How does a network of parallel capacitors look like ? How do you label potential for parallel capacitors ? Think on it.

Comment: If some of the capacitors are in series then that means that you have to go through two or more of them in order to reach from one side of the circuit to the other side. Look at what you've presented. Do you see any paths involving two or more capacitors in order to reach from one side of your circuit to the other?

Comment: @Mitchell I concluded that since all the capacitors are at same potential difference, they are all in parallel.

Comment: And that's the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drawing you have done is almost good enough to take you to the answer, provided you are able to redraw your circuit appropriately.

Look at this. (I have assumed you want equivalent capacitance b/w A and B)[image])

All of them are in parallel, so answer is 3C

Comment: How did you arrive at the simplified diagram?

Comment: You simplify the diagram by noticing the pd across the wire is zero, hence the pd across each capacitor is equal to the pd across the battery terminals.

Comment: You have to be slightly innovative. Remember that wire on paper, either long or short, is the same. In fact, even if its length is zero, doesn't matter. So that way, you can see all points marked X are connected to point A. Similarly for B.